# Challenging Oracle PL/SQL - Permutations of assigning one column to another sorted column

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm, plsql, permutation

Inputs are two data sets of G series and P series, which are strings in real data.

```
X = 3,

G series
G1
G2
G3

Y = 2,

P series
P1
P2
```

X Number of G series always > = Y number of P series.

I want to return all possible matches of available P values to G values except all same P values are assigned to G. In each group, sequence of G values are fixed, always G1,G2,G3.

One of expected results:

```
    1   G1  P1
    1   G2  P1
    1   G3  P2
---------------
    2   G1  P2
    2   G2  P2
    2   G3  P1
---------------
    3   G1  P1
    3   G2  P2
    3   G3  P1
---------------
    4   G1  P2
    4   G2  P1
    4   G3  P2
---------------
    5   G1  P1
    5   G2  P2
    5   G3  P2
---------------
    6   G1  P2
    6   G2  P1
    6   G3  P1
```

As you can see for X = 3, Y = 2, I want 6 or X*Y groups of possible permutations of pairings:

```
   | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 | Group 6 |
    -----------------------------------------------------------
   | G1 P1   | G1   P2 | G1 P1   | G1  P2  | G1 P1   | G1 P2   |
   | G2 P1   | G2   P2 | G2 P2   | G2  P1  | G2 P2   | G2 P1   |
   | G3 P2   | G3   P1 | G3 P1   | G3  P2  | G3 P2   | G3 P1   |
```

Pattern of P values to G1 - G3:
In other words, combinations of P like 112,221,121,212,122,211 are wanted.
but 111, 222 of P values are not wanted. Open to any way of sorting the six groups, as long as permutations are all listed.

Combination of the likes of followings are NOT wanted since all same Ps are assigned to G in same group:

```
 1   G1 P1
 1   G2 P1
 1   G3 P1
-----------
 2   G1 P2
 2   G2 P2
 2   G3 P2
```

My plan:
Do a Cartesian product of two data sets first:

```
1   G1  P1
2   G1  P2
3   G2  P1
4   G2  P2
5   G3  P1
6   G3  P2
```

Then insert X number of the Cartesian products, and hopefully to create a sequence of the combinations of the Cartesian products to get an expected result, but I couldn't find a pattern from it.

```
1   G1  P1
2   G2  P1
3   G3  P2
4   G1  P2
5   G2  P2
6   G3  P1
7   G1  P1
8   G2  P2
9   G3  P1
10  G1  P2
11  G2  P1
12  G3  P2
13  G1  P1
14  G2  P2
15  G3  P2
16  G1  P2
17  G2  P1
18  G3  P1
```

Also, you might notice possible result has X * (Y^X - Y) rows, in the above case when X = 3 and Y = 2, it's  3*(2^3-2) = 18 rows and 6 groups or (Y^X - Y) .

This procedure creates sequence that are not wanted:

```
Create or replace Procedure Permutation ( X in Number, Y in Number )                                                                        
AS j Number:=1;
Begin                                                                                                                               
For k in 1 .. X
   Loop
         For i in 1 .. X*Y                                                          
      Loop                                                          
                CASE 
          WHEN i = 1  THEN
            Insert into Table_1 ("INJECTION") values ( j );                                                                 
            Commit;
          WHEN mod(i,2)= 0 Then
            j :=  j + X ;                                                       
            Insert into Table_1 ("INJECTION") values ( j );                                                     
            Commit;
          WHEN mod(i,2)<>0 then
            j :=  j - Y ;                                                       
            Insert into Table_1 ("INJECTION") values ( j );                                                     
            Commit; 
          End CASE;
            End Loop;                                                           
         j := j + 1;                                                                
    Commit;                                                             
    End Loop;                                                                   
EXCEPTION                                                                       
   WHEN OTHERS                                                                      
   THEN                                                                     
      null;                                                                     
End;
```

Result: 1,4,2,5,3,6,7,10,8,11,9,12,13,16,14,17,15,18

```
1   G1  P1  1
2   G1  P2  4
3   G2  P1  2
4   G2  P2  5
5   G3  P1  3
6   G3  P2  6
7   G1  P1  7
8   G1  P2  10
9   G2  P1  8
10  G2  P2  11
11  G3  P1  9
12  G3  P2  12
13  G1  P1  13
14  G1  P2  16
15  G2  P1  14
16  G2  P2  17
17  G3  P1  15
18  G3  P2  18
```

Do a sort of the numbers you have the following, and are exactly the result not wanted:

```
1   G1  P1  1
3   G2  P1  2
5   G3  P1  3
2   G1  P2  4
4   G2  P2  5
6   G3  P2  6
7   G1  P1  7
9   G2  P1  8
11  G3  P1  9
8   G1  P2  10
10  G2  P2  11
12  G3  P2  12
13  G1  P1  13
15  G2  P1  14
17  G3  P1  15
14  G1  P2  16
16  G2  P2  17
18  G3  P2  18
```

I was wondering if there is a better approach to deal with this problem?
Arrays? levels?

Appreciate your inputs, many thanks.

---

Updates:

I'm thinking of algorithm, in essence, it's about selecting from
one P array `[P1,P2,P3,..PY]`
into G array `[G1,G2,G3...GX]`

```
Python 3.5.2, 

Create When X = 3, Y = 2, p = [1,2]
```

---

```
   import itertools
   for product in itertools.product([1,2],repeat=3):
        print (product)
```

---

```
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
(2, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 2)
```

which are exactly the result I wanted except with all repeating items, (1,1,1) and (2,2,2)...

Comment: You need to clarify your requirement.  The first five rows of your expected result are exactly the same as the first five rows of the combinations that are NOT wanted.  In what way are those two lists different?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Christian. If you take another look into it, might noticing that Not wanted results have same P values matched to G1,G2,G3 within a same group, such as G1P1, G2P1,G3P1 and G1P2, G2P2, G3P2. Expected results are groups like G1P1, G2P1,G3P2; P values are not all the same within the group.

Comment: Perhaps you need to define what you mean by a group?  I see pairings such as G1P1 and G2P1 appearing more than once in both the wanted and not wanted lists and there is nothing in your question to explain how that is the case.

Comment: Yes, I just revised the question, hopefully it's more easier to understand. Within each group, all G values are in a fixed order, G1,G2,G3, and I would like to pair P value with each G value, excluding pairings like G1 P1, G2 P1, G3 P1. and G1 P2, G2 P2, G3 P2. Thanks for your patience, Christian.

Comment: OK, so with X=3 and Y=2 you want six groups.  Each group should contain a possible combination of G (possible values 1..X) and P (possible values 1..Y).  ANY combination is valid.  However within a group no two combinations should be the same and there must be at least two distinct P values?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Ideally a procedure with 2 IN parameters , X and Y; Assuming X>Y and Y>=2. For each group, P values have to be not all the same.

Comment: Sorry - and also within each group there should be one combination for each of the possible G values?

Comment: Yes, G values always have the same sequence for all groups. Since I want to pair P to G thus permutations of G values are not necessary. Thanks!!

Comment: that's an interesting question.  I'd say it's more maths than PL/SQL but I'll give it some thought when I get some time at work...

Comment: one more question - in your example you want to include every possible G:P combination (total = 6) across six groups.  But there are only four unique groups of three that can be created under your rules.  So how should the other two groups be generated?  Is it random?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question of "only four unique groups of three that can be created under your rules". Combinations of six group of P values: 112, 221,121, 212,122, 211 are all unique, possible ways of assigning at least 2 different value to 3 spots and not random.

Comment: apologies - was getting mixed up - if I can think of a way out of this I'll get back to you.  As I said, it's really a maths problem and I think if you search online for algorithms for getting all combinations of two arrays you'll probably find a solution that you can port over to PL/SQL (most solutions will probably be written in other languages like Java and C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose to build a kind of branching tree. Each time you add a "G", your in fact adding a level to your tree.

the result you want in an ordered way are ***the routes to the leaves of the tree***, except the external ones (below draw).

```
              G1  G2  G3
        p1    ****************NO (p1 p1 p1)
       /
     p1
    /   \
   /     p2   (p1 p1 p2)
p1 
   \    p1    (p1 p2 p1)
    \  /
     p2 
      \ 
        p2    (p1 p2 p2)

        p1    (p2 p1 p1)
       /
     p1
    /   \
   /     p2   (p2 p1 p2)
p2       
   \    p1    (p2 p2 p1)
    \  /
     p2 
      \ 
        p2   **************NO (p2 p2 p1)
```

Each time you add a level, replicate the tuples for each P, and add each P to that same. Here is a way to build it in such an array (`l_ttab`), that you have remove first and last element (+ cross product with each G) to match your need.

## types

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tt_list AS TABLE OF t_list;
```

## copy function `cpy_node`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cpy_node(p_list in t_list)
  RETURN t_list
AS
  l_tab t_list := t_list();
BEGIN
  for i in 1..p_list.count loop
    l_tab.extend;
    l_tab(i):=p_list(i);
  end loop;
  RETURN l_tab;
END cpy_node;
```

## Generate a table from input list of "P" function `cto_table`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cto_table(p_sep in Varchar2, p_list IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN t_list
AS
  l_string VARCHAR2(32767) := p_list || p_sep;
  l_sep_index PLS_INTEGER;
  l_index PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  l_tab t_list := t_list();
BEGIN
  LOOP
    l_sep_index := INSTR(l_string, p_sep, l_index);
    EXIT
  WHEN l_sep_index = 0;
    l_tab.EXTEND;
    l_tab(l_tab.COUNT) := TRIM(SUBSTR(l_string,l_index,l_sep_index - l_index));
    l_index            := l_sep_index + 1;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN l_tab;
END cto_table;
```

## create* the list of ordered nodes:

```
declare
  l_ttab tt_list :=tt_list();
  l_ttab_next tt_list :=tt_list();
  l_tab_p t_list;    
  l_tab t_list;    
  p_nb_lvl pls_integer:=2;
begin
  l_tab_p := cto_table(',', 'p1, p2');
  -- initiate table with single nodes
  for i in 1..l_tab_p.count loop
    l_ttab.extend;
    l_tab :=t_list();
    l_tab.extend;
    l_tab(l_tab.count):=l_tab_p(i);
    l_ttab(l_ttab.count):=l_tab;
  end loop;
  -- ( p1 ) ( p2 )

  for k in 1..p_nb_lvl-1 loop
    l_ttab_next := tt_list();
    for j in 1..l_ttab.count loop
      for i in 1..l_tab_p.count loop
        -- copy from current list
        l_ttab_next.extend;
        l_ttab_next(l_ttab_next.count):=cpy_node(l_ttab(j));
        -- add node at the end
        l_ttab_next(l_ttab_next.count).extend;
        l_ttab_next(l_ttab_next.count)(k+1):=l_tab_p(i);
      end loop;
    end loop;  
    l_ttab := l_ttab_next;
  end loop;    

  -- display result
  for i in 1..l_ttab.count loop
    for j in 1..l_ttab(i).count loop
        dbms_output.put(l_ttab(i)(j)||' ');
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(chr(13)||'--');
  end loop;
  -- e.g. if p_nb_lvl=2:
  --(p1 p1) (p1 p2) (p2 p1) (p2 p2) (p1 p1) (p1 p2) ( p2 p1) ( p2 p2)

end;
```

*I don't say the above is optimal, because I recopy the tree each time, but it sounded easier that way for me.

Comment: Wow much appreciated. But as for t_list and tt_list, do I need to create varray type first?  Something like `CREATE TYPE t_list AS VARRAY(10) OF Varchar2;` maybe?

Comment: Yes, right, 2 types indeed. Added `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);` `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tt_list AS TABLE OF t_list;`

Comment: @fadedbrandnew, did it solve your issue? If its the case you can ***accept*** this solution (it will give you rep. points). If not, you may ask a new question that might have better audience.

Comment: Many thanks @J.Chomel, this is one of my ongoing side projects, and I have been busy meeting ddls of other urgent tasks these past couple days. I'll definitely look into it and will get back to you asap. Once again, appreciate your answer!